# Currency Drop down

Tags: forms

I need a currency drop down in my module to choose the currency with amount. Is there any feature to get this in Drupal?

Comment: currency for what? ubercart? commerce?

Comment: No I am making a fee management module

Comment: In that case, you define a form in a block and populate select box with currencies, manage them with AHAH/AJAX.

Comment: How can I get all the currencies available. Shall I populate them from database and add a table for currencies

Comment: You tagged this question "features."  Are you actually looking for a feature provided by the Drupal Features module?  Note that the Features tag is only for Features module related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Money](http://drupal.org/project/currency_cck) module provides a field allowing content editors to select an amount and currency.

Currently this module is only available for Drupal 6.x.  There's [an issue for porting it to Drupal 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/908480).

An alternative is the [Units of Measurement](http://drupal.org/project/units) module, which currently has a Drupal 7.x development release published.

Comment: can you please suggest me a best way to achieve the currency drop down. May I store all currencies in a file and then populate.

Comment: Both modules I linked to above already provide preconfigured currencies; you just need to enable the currencies you'd like to use, then add the field to the appropriate content type / entity.